# Fit the bag of routes with bag of rooms.

Tags: algorithm

I came up with the idea to exercise algorithmics when I received interesting task to do.

Namely, my university organizes "open days" and they want to guide the students with few different routes (for exmple 10 routes), so that all rooms, where are some exhibitions that took different time, were fit effectively to this routes. Important is that, that the rooms has limited size and different times.

Do you have any idea for effective algorithm? Or only greedy algo is possible here?

Comment: So, basically you want a scheduling algorithms that distributes the rooms/exhibits to different routes, probably with the added constraint that exhibits that are after one another on one route should also be close to each other? Why not just use the same route for each, but start at different rooms?

Comment: You want to find n routes in a graph, where each node has a max nr. of people and an average time spent. To be efficient rooms with about the same size should be on the same tour, because the smallest room will decide how many people can take that tour together. Additionally if the time spent per room is about the same, then you can send in a new group every time the old one left the room. Also they should be close together so you don't spend much time between rooms. So basically I would define a cost function that punishes unwanted behavior and then minimize the costs.

Comment: Although in practice, I would create tours about topics. E.g. the physics, biology, history etc. tour.